# Change bootstrap class name to my custome class name in html file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, prefix

I am trying to prefix bootstrap classes like (card, row, bt-button...) to (my-card,my-row,my-button...). The problem is, I am only allowed to use a plain html/css file.

```
instead of this
  <div class="row"> ... </div>

to this

<div class ="my-row">...</div>
```

I did some research, but mostly I need npm install or using scss, but not inside html file. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Compile the SCSS solution you found to a static CSS file then, and then use that ...?

Comment: What is your end goal? There may be a better way to accomplish that goal.

Comment: You cannot do this without SASS. The only way (probably) would be to copy Bootstrap's styles into your own classes which is both painful and a waste of time. If I can ask, why not just use Bootstrap's classes?

Comment: Thanks for the support! It is a project from a colleague, he has many html files using bootstrap in it. He wants for readability reasons to change to his own prefix classname. I found something with vue or sass , but not in html. That is why i am curious if this is possible using plain html.